# Why the view in Android kotlin application is not opening, however there are no errors?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have tried to make an Adroid application in Kotlin by tutorial on youtube.

It is suppose to show the Product list (like in an online store, where you can add products to cart).

Here is my Product.Activity.kt code:

```
class ProductActivity: AppCompatActivity(), ProductLoadListener {
    lateinit var productLoadListener: ProductLoadListener
    private lateinit var mainLayout: RelativeLayout
    private lateinit var recyclerproduct: RecyclerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_products)
    init()
        loadProductFromFirebase()
}
    private fun loadProductFromFirebase(){
        val productModels : MutableList<ProductModel> = ArrayList()
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Product")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object:ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot:DataSnapshot){
                    if(snapshot.exists())
                    {
                        for(productSnapshot in snapshot.children)
                        {
                            val productModel = productSnapshot.getValue(ProductModel::class.java)
                            productModel!!.key = productSnapshot.key
                            productModels.add(productModel)
                        }
                        productLoadListener.onProductLoadSuccess(productModels)
                    }
                        else
                            productLoadListener.onProductLoadFailed("Product items not exist")

                }
                override fun onCancelled(error:DatabaseError){
                    productLoadListener.onProductLoadFailed(error.message)
                }
            })
    }
    private fun init(){
    productLoadListener=this
        val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)
        recyclerproduct = findViewById(R.id.recycler_product)
        recyclerproduct.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        recyclerproduct.addItemDecoration(SpaceItemDecoration())
    }
    override fun onProductLoadSuccess(productModelList: List<ProductModel>?){
        val adapter = MyProductAdapter(this, productModelList!!)
        recyclerproduct.adapter = adapter

    }
    override fun onProductLoadFailed(message: String?){
        Snackbar.make(mainLayout,message?:"Unknown error",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Here is MyProductAdapter.kt code:

```
class MyProductAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val list: List<ProductModel>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyProductAdapter.MyProductViewHolder>() {

        class MyProductViewHolder(itemView:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
           var imageView:ImageView?=null
           var txtName:TextView?=null
           var txtPrice:TextView?=null

       init{
                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView) as ImageView
           txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName) as TextView
           txtPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice) as TextView

       }
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyProductViewHolder {
        return MyProductViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_product_item,parent,false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
         return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(list[position].image)
            .into(holder.imageView!!)
        holder.txtName!!.text = StringBuilder().append(list[position].name)
        holder.txtPrice!!.text = StringBuilder("EUR").append(list[position].price)

    }
}
```

Here is my activity_products view file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#E7E7E7"
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="16"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_navigation"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Product List"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="11"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnCart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                android:src="@drawable/shopping_cart"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge
                android:id="@+id/badge"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cartButton"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/cartButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                app:nbMaxTextLength="2"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_product"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the view to show list of products from Firebase database, which I imported. However, when I click on button, which should open this view, the application is crashing.

I don't know how to solve the error, since I see no errors in Logcat.

In my MainActivity.kt, I call the ProductActivity.kt view in following way:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.SelectProducts.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, ProductActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to check for Intent Creation.
Added a log statement to ensure that the Intent for ProductActivity is being created properly, however it didn't help and my application still crashed.

I assume, that the issue is specifically with ProductActivity code.

Can you please help?

Comment: There is *always* a stack trace in the log if the app crashes. There must be a filter turned on in your LogCat that is hiding it if you don’t see it.

Comment: By the way, never use `!!` unless you’re an intermediate level for the platform you’re coding on and know exactly when things cannot be null. Otherwise you will have frequent difficult bugs to fix. I’m advanced at Android and still never use `!!` because there are always better alternatives. Usually nullable things are nullable for a good reason so `!!` just means “please crash periodically”.

Comment: @Tenfour04, thank you , it actually resolved my issue and now app runs as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by re-writing the code to remove !!.

For example:

```
holder.txtName?.text = StringBuilder().append(list.getOrNull(position)?.name)
holder.txtPrice?.text = StringBuilder("EUR").append(list.getOrNull(position)?.price)
```